# Notebook Hardware Expandability

Tags: laptop, memory

I am unable to find a way to determine if I can expand RAM on my computer without opening it up.
I have googled and looked at the Toshiba website.

The Notebook I am using: [Notebook Linke](http://us.toshiba.com/computers/laptops/portege/R700/R705-P35/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Crucial's [Memory Advisor](http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/Toshiba-memory/Portege+R700+Series/Portege+R705-P35-upgrades.html) listing for this laptop, the maximum memory is 8 GB. Since the laptop only came with 4 GB, you can upgrade the memory. To get to 8 GB, you would need to put in 2 4GB DDR3 modules.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add extra RAM without opening the computer up. See page 52 of the [user's manual](http://www.manualusersguide.com/toshiba-portege-r705-p35-owners-manual-user-guide.html) for information on installing more memory.

Comment: +1 - this isn't an upgrade that it's possible to make without opening the system, and I'm confused how you could think it is otherwise.

Comment: They aren't asking how to *add* RAM without opening the computer, they are asking how to *determine if more RAM can be added* without opening the computer.